# SSRS Collected Pie Chart - showing orginal percentage

Tags: reporting-services, charts, pie-chart, ssrs-2012

I have created a collected pie chart in SSRS 2012. How do I get the child pie to show the original percentage value?

In this example, the Child Pie is worth 7% of the original. I want the child pie values to be the original value (such as 2%) and not 33%.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the value directly in the Values area, convert them to a % first.

For example instead of the value set to

```
Sum(Fields!Column.Value)
```

Set it to this

```
Sum(Fields!Column.Value) / Sum(Fields!Column.Value, "DataSet1")
```

(replace "DataSet1" with whatever the parent container's name is)

Then in the series label properties, remove the Label data setting and use the Number format to make it a %.

Here is a quick example

[image]